# BigQuery: Store semi-structured JSON data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data which can have varying `json` keys, I want to store all of this data in `bigquery` and then explore the available fields later.

My structure will be like so:

```
[
{id: 1111, data: {a:27, b:62, c: 'string'} },
{id: 2222, data: {a:27, c: 'string'} },
{id: 3333, data: {a:27} },
{id: 4444, data: {a:27, b:62, c:'string'} },
]
```

I wanted to use a `STRUCT` type but it seems all the fields need to be declared?

I then want to be able to query and see how often each key appears, and basically run queries over all records with for example `a` key as though it was in its own column.

Side note: this data is coming from URL query strings, maybe someone thinks it is best to push the full url and the use the functions to run analysis?

Comment: And what is the problem with a JSON column?

Comment: JSON column would need to be parsed into something else for any mathematical analysis. Yes initially I can store in a single col, but further steps are needed - unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two primary methods for storing semi-structured data as you have in your example:

**Option #1: Store JSON String**

You can store the `data` field as a JSON string, and then use the [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) function to pull out the values it can find, and it will return `NULL` for any value it cannot find.

Since you mentioned needing to do mathematical analysis on the fields, let's do a simple `SUM` for the values of `a` and `b`:

```sql
# Creating an example table using the WITH statement, this would not be needed
# for a real table.
WITH records AS (
  SELECT 1111 AS id, "{\"a\":27, \"b\":62, \"c\": \"string\"}" as data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222 AS id, "{\"a\":27, \"c\": \"string\"}" as data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333 AS id, "{\"a\":27}" as data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444 AS id, "{\"a\":27, \"b\":62, \"c\": \"string\"}" as data
)

# Example Query
SELECT SUM(aValue) AS aSum, SUM(bValue) AS bSum FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.a") AS INT64) AS aValue, # Extract & cast as an INT
    CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.b") AS INT64) AS bValue  # Extract & cast as an INT
  FROM records
)

# results
# Row | aSum | bSum
# 1   | 108  | 124
```

There are some pros and cons to this approach:

**Pros**

- The syntax is fairly straight forward
- Less error prone

**Cons**

- Store costs will be slightly higher since you have to store all the characters to serialize to JSON.
- Queries will run slower than using pure native SQL.

**Option #2: Repeated Fields**

BigQuery has [support for repeated fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated), allowing you to take your structure and express it natively in SQL.

Using the same example, here is how we would do that:

```sql
## Using a with to create a sample table
WITH records AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, data ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>>>[
  (1111, [("a","27"),("b","62"),("c","string")]),
  (2222, [("a","27"),("c","string")]),
  (3333, [("a","27")]),
  (4444, [("a","27"),("b","62"),("c","string")])
])),
## Using another WITH table to take records and unnest them to be joined later
recordsUnnested AS (
  SELECT id, key, value
  FROM records, UNNEST(records.data) AS keyVals
)

SELECT SUM(aValue) AS aSum, SUM(bValue) AS bSum
FROM (
  SELECT R.id, CAST(RA.value AS INT64) AS aValue, CAST(RB.value AS INT64) AS bValue
  FROM records R
    LEFT JOIN recordsUnnested RA ON R.id = RA.id AND RA.key = "a"
    LEFT JOIN recordsUnnested RB ON R.id = RB.id AND RB.key = "b"
)

# results
# Row | aSum | bSum
# 1   | 108  | 124
```

As you can see, to perform a similar, it is still rather complex. You also still have to store items like strings and `CAST` them to other values when necessary, since you cannot mix types in a repeated field.

**Pros**

- Store size will be less than JSON
- Queries will typically execute faster.

**Cons**

- The syntax is more complex, not as straight forward

Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Amazing, what a great answer! I will go for the `JSON` string option - mainly because I am not a DB person and have no real grasp of `STRUCT` in this case, let me know if you have a good resource for this past what is on the BQ website.